# How to store a JSON with null values with cmsgpack and Lua in Redis?

Tags: json, redis, lua, msgpack

I've been reading the documentation about cjson and know about the conversion of null values to [cjson.null](https://www.kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson-manual.html#_decode) values (because of no possible way to store nil in Lua tables. This works well if I use cjson.decode and cjson.encode.

However, when I try to pack and unpack the contents of the table with [cmsgpack](https://github.com/antirez/lua-cmsgpack), the keys with null values are not present. I use code similar to this [one](https://gist.github.com/fritzy/7340641).

How do you solve this problem? Do you replace null values with a especial value ({isnull: true} before calling cmspack.pack and later, replace back {isnull: true} to null) or use any other technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick research and didn't find any msgpack library that handles `null` values in hash tables. I'm not saying that such a library doesn't exist, though.

I've chosen another approach. Since `lua-cmsgpack` doesn't do anything special for handling `null` values when decoding MessagePack binary data and `nil` values are problem in tables only, we can add some special case code for hash → table decoder.

Actually, the patch is pretty trivial:

```
--- a/lua_cmsgpack.c
+++ b/lua_cmsgpack.c
@@ -565,6 +565,10 @@ void mp_decode_to_lua_hash(lua_State *L, mp_cur *c, size_t len) {
         mp_decode_to_lua_type(L,c); /* key */
         if (c->err) return;
         mp_decode_to_lua_type(L,c); /* value */
+        if (lua_isnil(L, -1)) {
+            lua_pop(L, 1);
+            lua_pushlightuserdata(L, NULL);
+        }
         if (c->err) return;
         lua_settable(L,-3);
     }
```

Here the second call of `mp_decode_to_lua_type` converts a hash entry *value* to a corresponding Lua type value, and when the value is `nil` (that is, `null` in MessagePack), we replace it with a light userdata (`NULL` pointer). The same userdata (`NULL` pointer) is used as the `cjson.null` value.

We don't need to patch the encoder because it encodes any unsupported value including any userdata to `null`, that is, you can use `cjson.null` userdata to represent `null` values (and cjson.decode does just that). When the hash is decoded, you'll get the same userdata.

The same trick can be applied to array-like tables but it is not necessary if you know a size of a table — you can iterate the table from the first to the last index.

```lua
local cjson = require('cjson')
local cmsgpack = require('cmsgpack')

local encoded_hash = cmsgpack.pack({k1 = nil, k2 = cjson.null, k3 = 'baz'})
local decoded_hash = cmsgpack.unpack(encoded_hash)
print('decoded_hash.k2 == cjson.null?', decoded_hash.k2 == cjson.null)
for k, v in pairs(decoded_hash) do
    print(k, '->', v)
end

local encoded_array = cmsgpack.pack({'foo', nil, cjson.null, 'bar'})
local decoded_array = cmsgpack.unpack(encoded_array)
print('#decoded_array =', #decoded_array)
for i = 1, 4 do
    print(i, '->', decoded_array[i])
end
```

Output:

```
decoded_hash.k2 == cjson.null?  true
k3  ->  baz
k2  ->  userdata: (nil)
#decoded_array =    4
1   ->  foo
2   ->  nil
3   ->  userdata: (nil)
4   ->  bar
```

Thanks to LuaRocks we don't even need to support the fork of the library for such a trivial patch. Patches can be included directly in rockspec file. I've created a gist with modified rockspec: https://gist.github.com/un-def/d6b97f5ef6b47edda7f65e0c6144663c

You can install a patched version of the library with the following command:

```sh
luarocks install https://gist.github.com/un-def/d6b97f5ef6b47edda7f65e0c6144663c/raw/8fe2f1ad70c75bfe2532a1f4cf9213f4e28423d3/lua-cmsgpack-0.4.0-0.rockspec
```

Comment: Oh, I just realized that redis is compiled into a single binary. You can't just replace `cmsgpack.so` with the patched one because it doesn't exist, you have to recompile the whole redis if you want to change something in bundled Lua modules. It is possible but it is not worth it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. I'm no expert in Lua and didn't know about luarocks. Pity I had to recompile Redis, don't know if I will do that (because imposed platform limitations) or look for another alternative.

Comment: LuaRocks is just a package manager for Lua, like npm for JS or pip for Python. Anyway, LuaRocks is not an option in case of Redis. I only mentioned LuaRocks as a way to build (and play with) the patched version. But as I discovered later, Lua in Redis is compiled without the facility for dynamic linking. It can be enabled – https://fnordig.de/2014/07/27/extending-redis-with-lua-packages/ – but, again, it requires recompiling Redis. That being so, your idea with a sentinel object (replace `cjson.null` with `{isnull = true}` before packing and vice versa after unpacking) seems the best option.